# If I buy a game or DLC on one computer via Steam, can I play it on another?

Tags: steam

I wanna buy it on my friends macbook tonight, then play it on my pc tomorrow night.

Comment: -1 Srsly? You could find the answer in Steam FAQ in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 10):

If you buy something through Steam under your account, you can play it on any PC using that account (with the exception of some games that have a limited number of activations enforced by 3rd-party DRM, but this concern doesn't apply to MW2 DLC).

Comment: The "under your account" bit is the important part. If you do this, make sure you are signed in to your account, and not your friend's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I do not see the need for posting this, as the Steam FAQs will give you an answer. However assuming both you and your friend have internet connection, as long as you sign in with the same Steam profile on both computers the game will appear in your library on any computer with that profile signed in on. Then just double click the game to download it to that computer. However as another answer said, you cannot play them at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

yes, but you cant at the same time, because it will log the other pc out from the account, you can share your library but still you wont be able to play at the same time

Comment: Your response comes a bit late, and OP hasn't logged in since he asked it, more than on year ago. So... it may not be *that* useful. Try to find a more recent question, which doesn't already have a good answer ;)